# Node.js - Https Server

Tags: node.js, https

```js
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('fixtures/agent2-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('fixtures/agent2-cert.pem')
};

https.createServer(options, function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(8000);
```

Нужно создать HTTPS сервер, но после запуска у меня выдает в консоли вот что

```
C:\Users\Сергей\Desktop\Chat>cmd /k node aaa.js
fs.js:500
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\Users\╨б╨╡╤А╨│╨╡╨╣\Desktop\Chat\fix
tures\agent2-key.pem'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:500:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:352:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\╨б╨╡╤А╨│╨╡╨╣\Desktop\Chat\aaa.js:5:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)

C:\Users\Сергей\Desktop\Chat>
```

Устанавливал ssl-root-cas, работаю в phpstorm, подскажите как его запустить.

Comment: long story short: вынесите приложение из русскоязычных папок или разберитесь, где внутри летит кодировка.

Comment: т.е. key и cret?

Comment: Т.е. кодировка. Видите, что случилось со словом "Сергей"? Хотя, возможно, у вас просто действительно там файла не валяется.

Comment: Фрагменты кода предназначены для комбинаций HTML+JS+CSS, которые могут быть запущены прямо в браузере. Для остальных случаев следует использовать простые блоки кода.

Comment: Ваши файлы сертификатов действительно находятся в C:\Users\Сергей\Desktop\Chat\fixtures?